# Android Studio - Cmake get current Flavour (build variant)

Tags: android-studio, cmake

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2 with Cmake 3.6. I am trying to get access to the current build flavour that is selected in Android Studio via Cmake. Is that possible?

Something like I get current directory path with

> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}

can I get current build flavour somehow in Cmake ?

Comment: I have the same problem, any chance you got a solution for this?